# Creating a computed column from expressions used to created 2 earlier computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, calculated-columns

**SOLVED MY PROBLEM... SEE SECOND PIECE OF CODE**

This is my sql statement which compares 2 rows serial numbers from different tables. if there is a match then a yes is displayed, but if there is not a match then a no is displayed
This is done twice for 2 different reasons on different tables

```
SELECT  table1.serial1, table1.serial2,
        CASE WHEN table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol1],
        CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2]
FROM    table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table2.serial1 = table1.serial1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EPG
            ON table3.serial2 = table1.serial2
```

what I want to do then is create another column which places yes in the row if wither the first or second column are yes otherwise it will display a no. I realise you cant compre computed columns so what i was looking to do was repeat the expressions and have an or statement with no luck. I'm not very experienced writing anyhting other then basic sql... This is mty attempt:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT table1.serial1, table1.serial2,
        CASE WHEN table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol1],
        CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2],
        CASE WHEN table3.serial2 IS NULL OR table2.serial1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS [computedCol2]
FROM    table1
        LEFT JOIN table2
            ON table2.serial1 = table1.serial1
        LEFT JOIN dbo.EPG
            table3.serial2 = table1.serial2
```

Comment: Solved my own problem. Please see second piece of code for solution

Answer (score 0):

- `table3.serial2 OR table2.serial1 IS NULL` isn't the condition you're looking for. You need `table3.serial2 IS NULL OR table2.serial1 IS NULL`.
- You're trying to return two different values with the same alias, `[computedCol2]`.

Comment: Thanks but they were just errors when i was renaming the tables and things to post here. The edit better represents what I have now.